# Class.getResourceAsStream don't work in the installed eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, resources, manifest.mf

I have following code in the my plug-in project

```
Class.getResourceAsStream("/file.png");
```

And my file is placed in the src/main/resources.

When I run my plug-in application from the eclipse run configuration dialog everything is fine.
But, when I install mentonied plug-in on the standalone instance of the eclipse, have null pointer exception.

I have add my resources folder to the jar in following way.

```
source.. = src/main/java/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               target/dependency/jfxrt-8.0.jar,\
               src/main/resources/

               target/dependency/jfxrt-8.0.jar
```

But, meanwhile problem is present.

Where I'm wrong and how to solve my problem?

Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: Check that file is actually present in `jar`.

Comment: It's present - I have check

Comment: *Where* is it in the jar, and what does the manifest say is the plug-in's classpath?

Comment: Well, structure of the jar is following
/
com - there is *.class files
meta-inf\
             MANIFEST.MF
src
   \main
     \resources - my png files there
     
target


Classpath from manifest.mf is
Bundle-ClassPath: .

Comment: There is my MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyEditor
Bundle-SymbolicName: myview
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: IDC
Require-Bundle:
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Export-Package: